# Serialize data to std::vector<uint8_t> - Protobuf C++

Tags: c++, parsing, protocol-buffers, std

I'm stuck in a simple but hurting task: data parsing in C++. I need to serialize the data content from a Protobuf object to `std::vector<uint8_t>`. I've seen several examples to serialize the data to `*void` or `char[]` buffers using the `SerializeToArray` method, but not for what I need. I'd like to have a hand with this, thanks for your support.

Note: I need `std::vector<uint8_t>`, not `std::vector<uint8_t>&` nor others.

Comment: What have you got so far? You should ad it because maybe it only needs a little tweak. If it doesn't, knowing where you went off the correct path is vital to properly explaining the problem so that you don't fall into the same trap again later.

Comment: A std::vector<uint8_t> is effectively holding a byte-buffer as it’s internal array, so a simple void * p = &vec[0]; should be enough to let you serialize into the vector using the methods you already know.  (Be sure to resize() the vector to the appropriate size first!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The straight-forward solution is to presize the `std::vector<uint8_t>` to the correct size:

```cpp
  size_t nbytes = std::vector<uint8_t> v(proto_object.ByteSizeLong());
  /* The test is necessary becaue v.data could be NULL if nbytes is 0 */
  if (nbytes)
    proto_object.SerializeToArray(v.data(), nbytes);
```

The only problem here is that the contents of `v` are set to 0 by the constructor just before being overwritten by `SerializeToArray`. That's not a bug; the code will work fine. But it's an inefficiency.

Being able to create vectors of uninitialised values is a long-standing discussion point. There are ways to do it, but the simple ones require using a type subtly different from `std::vector<uint8_t>`: one possibility is to use a vector with a custom allocator; another is to use a non-initialising data type based on `uint8_t`. Both of those are annoying because you can't change the allocator or value type of a vector without copying it, which defeats the purpose.

So the easiest thing is to just accept the inefficiency, which is probably not so serious because the cost of sending the serialised data to wherever it is going is likely to dwarf the unnecessary initiliasation. In any event, clearing memory is certainly cheaper than copying from a temporary buffer, and it doesn't require creating the temporary buffer.

Comment: Looks like this ticks all the boxes of @JairoReyes with the calculation of the size of the message.

Comment: The code example needs fixing

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use an `std::vector` you could do it like this (from the top of my head):

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>

// Adjust this value to match your maximum message size.
constexpr MAX_N_BYTES = 100;

// Allocate enough space for your message in the vector.
std::vector<uint8_t> vec;
vec.reserve(MAX_N_BYTES);

// The allocation of your message.
YourMessage msg;

// Set some data
msg.set_x(1234);

// Next serialize to the data into the vector.
msg.SerializeToArray(vec.data(), vec.max_size());
```

However I would not advice you to use an `std::vector` like this. The vector container is really designed to be used top level managing memory underneath.

A more suitable container in my opinion would be `std::array`. This is a container more closely resembling a normal C style array. For which the implementation would look like:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>

// Adjust this value to match your maximum message size.
constexpr MAX_N_BYTES = 100;

// Allocate the array
std::array<uint8_t, MAX_N_BYTES> array;

// The allocation of your message.
YourMessage msg;

// Set some data
msg.set_x(1234);

// Next serialize to the data into the array.
msg.SerializeToArray(array.data(), MAX_N_BYTES);
```

Note in both case you really need to know the maximum size of your message in advance. This to allocate the proper amount of memory.

Comment: It seems ok, however, the allocation size must be dynamic.
I thought this approach:
```ProtoModel proto_object;
    proto_object.set_data(data...);
    
    size_t size_package = proto_object.ByteSizeLong();
    
    std::vector<uint8_t> payload;
    
    void *buffer_msg = malloc(size_package);
    proto_object.SerializeToArray(buffer_msg, size_package);
    
    payload.resize(size_package);
    
    memcpy(payload.data(), buffer_msg, size_package);
```
It seems to works as desired.

Comment: @bart: calling `vec.reserve(n)` doesn't let you treat `vec.data()` as though it were of size `n`, much less `vec.max_size()` (which is a very large number; the size of the largest vector supported by this implementation; I guess you meant `vec.capacity()`.) The problem is that `vec.size()` continues to be 0 after that call, so any later attempt to use the values in the vector will founder. And there's no way to just set the size of a vector without clearing the added elements. So you should use `vec.resize(n)`, not `vec.reserve()`.

Comment: @Jairo: that's the basic idea, but there's no need for the dynamically allocated `buffer_msg`. Just make `payload` the correct size in the first place (which will unnecessarily clear it, but that's cheaper than a copy), and then pass `payload.data()` to `SerializeToArray`.

Comment: @rici Thank you for the feedback. I will change the code to use `capacity()` as that is indeed the function I should use. With regards to using `resize()` I have my reservations. The way I read the documentation `resize()` will increase or decrease the allocated memory for the vector. `reserve()` will only increase if required.

Comment: @bart: in this case, the vector is newly created so it has no allocation yet. But you cannot assume that data()  will return the reserved memory if the reserved memory is not yet used. If size() is 0, data() can return nullptr. (Even if size() is greater than 0, the standard doesn't let you use more than size() elements in data(), although it will probably work in practice. But the fact that you've saved data in those elements doesn't help because the vector can only be accessed up to size() and you can't increase size without losing what you wrote.

Comment: @rici Understood